# How do I get a list of an Object?

Tags: c#, linq

I am very new at Linq. I have a problem. I am trying to retrieve a list of Files. Here is the query I wrote.

```
var DataSource = from d in db.Directories
                 join dok in db.Files on d.DirectoryId equals dok.DirectoryId
                 where dok.SomeId == (int)cboSome.SelectedValue
                 select new  { d };
```

This retrieves the right d's but I want to retrieve a List of Files. When I take the datasource by casting var to Files, it returns null. How can I do that? Sorry if it is too simple.

Comment: Not sure what your question is...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What result do you want?

If you want to result the objects from `db.Directories`, try something like this:

```
 var DataSource = (from d in db.Directories
                             join dok in db.Files on d.DirectoryId equals dok.DirectoryId
                             where dok.SomeId == (int)cboSome.SelectedValue
                             select d).ToList();
```

Remember to call the `ToList()` method.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked. I didn't know the difference between select new and select.

Comment: select new returns an nonnymus type which wraps up the actual object in your case.
Forget that stuff when you begin with learning Linq

Answer (score 2):

There is a `.ToList()` extension method that should convert any `IEnumerable` into a `List`.

eg `var List = DataSource.ToList();`